# chartjs angular update order

Tags: angular, chart.js

Got a question about chartjs in an angular11 environment.
I have 2 charts

appcomponent.html:

```
<div class="col-sm">
  <canvas id="bl" ></canvas>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  <canvas id="bl2" ></canvas>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
            testChart: any;
            testChart2: any;
            ...
  constructor(private dataSvc:DataRetrieverService){
    dataSvc.getUsers.subscribe( data=> {
      if(!data) return;
      this.Users = data;
      this.Users.forEach(x => {
        this.UsersLabels.push(x.StoreDateTime);
        this.UsersAmount.push(x.Amount);
        this.CreateCharts();
      })
    })

    dataSvc.getParts.subscribe( data=> {
      if(!data) return;
      this.Parts = data;
      this.Parts.forEach(x => {
        this.PartsLabels.push(x.StoreDateTime);
        this.PartsAmount.push(x.Amount);
        this.CreateCharts();
      })
    })
  }
  
  

  CreateCharts(){
    if(this.testChart){
      this.testChart.destroy()
    }
    if(this.testChart2){
      this.testChart2.destroy()
    }
    
    this.testChart = new Chart('bl', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.UsersLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Users',
            data: this.UsersAmount,
            borderColor: '#01c38c',
            backgroundColor: '#01c38c',
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {... }
      }
    });

    this.testChart2 = new Chart('bl2', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.PartsLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Parts',
            data: this.PartsAmount,
            borderColor: '#01c38c',
            backgroundColor: '#01c38c',
            fill: true
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {...
      }
    });
```

Is creating the **testChart: Any** the correct thing to do?

Why do I have to call **this.CreateCharts()** after every data retrieval from the service in order to make it work?

I would expect if I would do a **this.CreateCharts()** at the very last step of the constructor it would also work, but then my chart is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subscribing to two [`Observable`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable) obtained from `dataSvc.getUsers` and `dataSvc.getParts`, corresponding results will be delivered asynchronously, certainly after the invocation of the `constructor` has finished. Therefore, If with given code, you would invoke `CreateChart()` at the end of the `constructor` only, you would see two empty charts because `UsersLabels`, `UsersAmount`, `PartsLabels` and `PartsAmount` are still empty arrays at this point.

It's however needless to recreate both charts each time any `Observable` delivers new data. You better split `CreateChart()` into separate methods, one for each chart. Also instead of using `chart.destroy()`, you should better simply update the existing chart `data` and invoke `chart.update()` afterwards. Please take a look at the section [**Adding or Removing Data**](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#adding-or-removing-data) of the Chart.js documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes perfect sense to me